# wp-login.php entering password nothing happens

Tags: wp-admin, login

I have a website prettypeople.nl and whenever I try to login as an admin whether at /wp-admin or /wp-login and input the correct credentials, nothing happens!

The page refreshes and if I check the logs I cant find anything!

What can I do?

Link changes from `prettypeople.nl/wp-login` to:

```
https://prettypeople.nl/wp-login.php?redirect_to=https%3A%2F%2Fprettypeople.nl%2Fprettypeople%2F%2Fwp-admin%2F&reauth=1
```

It authenticates the password credentials and wants to redirect me to  the correct page, but doesn't.

Comment: I am using https://prettypeople.nl/wp-login.php and it shows "ERROR: The password you entered for the username admin is incorrect. Lost your password?", so it seems to be working as expected.

Comment: Yeah if you input the correct password, not if you input the correct password

Comment: where is the incorrect word supposed to go in your comment? like that it doesn't make any sense

Comment: Yeah if you input the incorrect password, not if you input the correct password. Sorry!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Link `https://prettypeople.nl/wp-admin` redirects to

```
https://prettypeople.nl/wp-login.php?redirect_to=https://prettypeople.nl/prettypeople//wp-admin/&reauth=1
```

According to me, the link should end like this:

```
?redirect_to=https://prettypeople.nl/wp-admin/&reauth=1
```

Check `siteurl` and `home` options in `{wp_}options` table and rewrite rules in `.htaccess` file .